# Create a new VM from existing VHD

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I use to have a running Windows 7 VHD on Windows Server 2008 R2. While playing around with the things I seem to have deleted snapshot files .AVHD.

Is it possible to create new virtual machine with existing .VHD and run the same OS which was installed there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've deleted all the snapshots, then creating a new VM from that VHD file will be like reverting to the oldest snapshot.  All changes since you took that first snapshot will be gone.

Comment: that should be fine, please suggest some guidelines on how to do this.

Comment: Run the "new virtual machine" wizard.  When it asks whether you wan to use an existing VHD file, point to the one you have.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new VM
When it asks you to configure a virtual hard disk click 'use existing virtual hard disk'
Point to your VHD
Configure the VM's hardware settings
Load the VM

It will load using your Win7 VM, from the last snapshot.